# php convert multidimensional array in twig code

Tags: php, twig

I have try many way but didn't work want to convert this php code in to twig code.

```
<?php echo $dynamic[$language[language_id]][header]; ?>
```

Please help me with that

Comment: Is that line correct? Unless `language_id` and `header` are defined constants. they will each trigger a "Use of undefined constant" warning.

Comment: yes in other version i am using same line but in twig i can't convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the array notation inside `twig` as well

```
{{ dynamic[language['language_id']]['header'] }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/shxkkm)

As an alternative, u could use the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function. But this one is too complex for this situation imho

```
{{ attribute(attribute(dynamic, language['language_id']), 'header') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is the [`attribute()` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html):

`{{ attribute(dynamic, language['language_id']['header']) }}`

Comment: If you only use `attribute` once, you might want to move the `)` behind `['language_id']`

Comment: In fact, I was misreading the question and it doesn't seem necessary to use the function at all. The first example from your answer seems to be the best solution.